# sql: Scan error on column index 1, name "u.duration": converting driver.Value type []uint8 ("MORE") to a int: invalid syntax

Tags: postgresql, go

I have enum filed in the table. When I do a SELECT query with the help of  `Select()` method, I get:

> sql: Scan error on column index 1, name "u.duration": converting driver.Value type []uint8 ("MORE") to a int: invalid syntax

my DB structure

```
CREATE TYPE duration_type AS ENUM ('TWO_MONTHS', 'SIX_MONTHS', 'ONE_YEAR','MORE');
CREATE TABLE shake_hands
(
    id                      uuid,
    duration                duration_type NOT NULL,
    phone_number            TEXT,
    email_address           TEXT,
    created_at              TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

my structs

```
type DurationType int

type ShakesHands struct {
    ID          uuid.UUID  `db:"id"`
    PhoneNumber string `db:"phone_number"`
    Duration    DurationType
    Email       *string   `db:"email_address"`
    ModelIds    []string
}
```

Anything else need to be pasted here?

Comment: You can implement the `sql.Scanner` and `driver.Valuer` interfaces for your `DurationType`.

Comment: @mkopriva  can you please explain a bit ? Don't have idea about this

Comment: Here's an example [`sql.Scanner`](https://play.golang.org/p/31LfdCd6S9Q). For the `driver.Valuer` you pretty much do the reverse, there are many examples all over, here on SO, on github, internet.

Comment: @mkopriva got your point . but how this scan function got execute ?

Comment: It's executed automatically by the `database/sql` package or the driver package, I forget which one exactly, either way you do not have to execute it yourself. Same for the `Value() (dirver.Value, error)` method of the `driver.Valuer` interface.

Comment: @mkopriva so ideally where I should paste this code ?  in repo files ?